# Titanium StoreKit module won't verify test account

Tags: ios, titanium, storekit

I have a recurring subscription product as an in app purchase in my Titanium app. When I go to test this, it retrieves the correct product from iTunes and I get almost all the way through checkout, but before it lets me purchase, it says "Verification Required Before you can make purchases, you must tap Continue to verify your payment info. [Environment: Sandbox]"

When I press Continue, it takes me into the App Store and just has a dialog box that says "[Environment: Sandbox]" with a Cancel and Continue button. If I press Continue again, it asks me for my password. After entering, I just get the same dialog again. This continues endlessly.

In the Titanium console, it shows "Error in transaction: Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

I'm debugging on an iPhone 5S with iOS 7, using Titanium SDK 3.1.3 and StoreKit module version 3.0.0. Any ideas?

=======

*EDIT:* As it turns out, when you create a Test User in iTunes Connect, Apple sends a verification email to the email address used. If you verify the new account, it becomes an actual iTunes account, no longer a test account, and you get an endless loop of verifying payment info. DO NOT verify a Test User account.