# Apple Verification Email requested for Sandbox Tester User ID

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm having a problem getting the Test User sandbox IDs I've created in iTunesConnect to purchase a non-consumable product. I wait a day after I create the IDs before trying to use them. First, I make sure no ID is signed in according to Settings/iTunes & App Store on the device. Then, when I run my app in Simulator on a real device and click my Buy button and sign on with a Test User ID, I get a popup saying the ID must be verified and that a verification email will be sent if I click the Verify button. Now, I know I should not verify a Test ID (because according to [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622470/titanium-storekit-module-wont-verify-test-account), that action turns the ID into an actual account). I'm also given the option to Ignore the verification -- if I click that, nothing happens -- I'd expect the purchase process to continue, but it doesn't. Yes, of course, I'm running the simulation on an actual device. And, though I start out with no ID entered in Settings for iTunes/App Store, when I go back after receiving the above, my own Apple ID now appears as signed-in! Could this have something to do with my activating Apple's Two-Factor Authentication? I just turned that on last week.

Comment: Sign in with your sandbox user in settings and then attempt the purchase in your app

Comment: No, that doesn't work -- as it says in the Apple documentation, if you put a Sandbox Tester User ID in Settings, the ID is changed to a real account.

Comment: That's how I have always done it in the past, but it seems that the sandbox purchasing/user stuff is broken at the moment.  People are reporting it on the Apple Developer forums and I have seen a few questions here too.  I just tried to create a new account and I can't purchase whether I verify it or not.

Comment: Facing the  same problem here. After creating new sandbox tester accounts, when I open the app ( having my iPhone settings clear of any account ) it asks whether to use existing apple id or create new one. When I enter the details of sandbox account, it shows a pop up stating "Apple ID Verification required" with option of going to settings. I tried various territories but continue facing this. Anyone found a solution yet ?

Comment: Same problem.  It appears this is newer sandbox accounts because older ones we have are working.  Unfortunately they aren't always reusable in our case.

Comment: I have same problem, I tried everything. i see Apple Id Verification popup when i try to buy in IAP via sandbox tester.. I tried very old sandbox tester from different developer account. It worked but i had this error in last step "you are not authorized to make purchases of this in app in sandbox".. I think so it is about different developer account..

Comment: I called Apple two days day ago and they said they were aware and working on it. Got email yesterday saying it was resolved. I tried, still not working. Called Apple again today because still not working.

Comment: Yep I have the same problem.  Wants me to verify the account, though the test user has a fake email for testing! Apple drives me crazy.

Answer (score 5):

I have finally got iTunes Connect sandbox users to work. In order to do so I **had** to verify the sandbox user's account and hence needed a valid email address to do so.

**Steps highlighted at the end**

This goes against how I had always created and used sandbox users from day 1, but either there's been an undocumented change or is the current hack for the current iTunesConnect server maladies.

- I can confirm that the receipt generated is a sandbox receipt.
- The user is a sandbox user.
- I have not entered nor paid with a credit card.

**Steps to solve**

1. Go to iTunesConnect -> Users & Roles -> Sandbox User and add a new user
2. Use a **valid** email address. Tip: A real gmail account and the `+` symbol can generate many valid emails. i.e. `jon.doe+1@gmail.com`, `jon.doe+2@gmail.com` etc where `jon.doe@gmail.com` is a valid gmail account.
3. Wait for verify email from iTunes.
4. Verify the sandbox user by clicking on verification link. Tip: Use incognito browser to keep your real and sandbox Apple sessions separate.

Comment: I did not get + suffix trick to work either. I think support for that has been removed.

Comment: can we use existing apple ID as email id for sandbox tester ?

Comment: Last I checked (a long time ago) you couldn't use an existing Apple ID.  I REALLY wouldn't do this anyway.

You are bound to get into a funny state which you can't work out if it's your fault or the fault of using an id existing in two systems.

Comment: i have tried using this trick but it won't work for me when i am going to add + sign in real email its showing me weird error like "this field is invalid" in password textbox but if i use "_" instead of "+" it will work. but can't get any verification mail please help you guys have solved this problem