# Apple Connect new sandbox users not working

Tags: ios, debugging, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have been trying for days to create a new sandbox account for testing a change I've made to my IAP code. I have a working account (a gmail +x account) but it already "owns" all of my products. I want another account to do more testing, but every time I create a new one, I always does "Apple ID Verification" and forces me to do a password change. Here is what I do:

- log out of iTunes account on the test device in Settings
- create a new account on Connect (I've tried Canada and US stores)
- verify the account via the email that is sent
- delete the existing app from the test device
- build the app and select a product from my IAP interface
- choose 'Use Existing Apple ID' at the prompt

At this point I enter the new account credentials and I get the dreaded Apple ID Verification alert. If I choose Settings, it takes me to a password change view. If I change the password, subsequent logins insist that I have the wrong ID/password. If I try my existing account, it works fine.

I don't attempt to use the new account with a direct login to the app store. There are many posts on this from years ago but nothing recent. Maybe something has changed or broken?

Comment: yeah since past few days the sandbox server doesnt work. I'm waiting as well. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70535

Comment: It's related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528588/apple-verification-email-requested-for-sandbox-tester-user-id. We still don't have an answer though.

Comment: Test users in Appstore Connect work good for me.